# flutter: Dialog not dismiss with tap when changed it's default position

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to show a dialog at the `bottomCenter` of the page. So in order to do so, I added `Align` into my custom widget. Now the Dialog is shown at the correct position.

```
 Dialog(
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
    ),
    elevation: 0,
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    insetPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 30.0),
    child: Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(...
```

The problem is:

Now I set true to `barrierDismissible` because I want the user to close the dialog when Tapping on the screen, but since the dialog position is bottom, the dialog wont dismiss when Tap on the top of screen? It is dismissed when Tapped around itself.
How can I fix the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you pushed the content down, which means that the empty space at the top is not a barrier.
It is possible as an option to wrap Align in a GestureDetector and handle the click by calling Navigator.pop (context);

Answer (score 1):

According greengo's solution with little change, I changed my dialog to this:

```
  GestureDetector(
    onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context),
    child: Dialog(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
      ),
      elevation: 0,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      insetPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 30.0),
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(...
```

And now I can close dialog when tap on screen.

Answer (score 0):

if greengo's solution doesn't work, you could add a boolean value to the page (as statefulWidget), set it to true when opening the dialog and add an onTap event on the Scaffold. If this boolean variable equals true (dialog is opened), then you call Navigator.pop(context).

Comment: I add answer according greengo's solution with little change